# wp_remote_get - curl error 28 connection timed out - using SANS in URL

Tags: ssl, wp-remote-get

I have WAMP installed and everything works fine locally with this wordpress code, but as soon as I upload this to our hosting company: goDaddy, I get a connection time out error.   I'm not really familiar with using a SSL certificates, but I can see we use them and the Subject Alternative Name or SAN on the certificate is the same URL used as in my wp_remote_get().

```
 $original_search = get_search_query();    
 /* Query not Found - External API performs secondary search */

$remoteQuery = "https://ecom.oursite.com/cgi-bin/company/ecom/wp_api.html?part=";
$response = wp_remote_get( $remoteQuery .       
    $original_search, array(
        'timeout' => 30,
        'sslverify' => false,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'user-agent'  => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . home_url()
    )
);
```

Comment: Try contacting GoDaddy. Or remove or comment out the `timeout` parameter — `//'timeout' => 30,` — or increase the value, e.g. to 60.

Comment: An update... Turned out to be a firewall blocking incoming i/p address issue.  I spoke with the owner of the company (he is a techie) and he opened the i/p address and port that I needed to make the wp_remote_get call. Note: you may need to use phpinfo() to find the i/p address of the server where your wordpress site is hosted.